# cakePHP - how to ovveride the default routing?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a controller, and I have several aliases for a single function in it.
eg:

```
Router::connect(
   '/controllerX/:method', 
   array('controller' => 'controllerX', 'action' => 'bigApple'),
   array('method'=>'help|ask|read', pass => array(method))
 );
```

Now, for some reason(don't ask..) I want to keep the original methods in the controller, but I don't want them to be available for direct access.
Meaning: in the controller there will be functions named: `ask`,`help`, and `read`, but they won't be accessible for direct call.
if someone will enter the url `/controllerX/ask`, or `/controllerX/help`, i want him to be routed to somewhere else.

is it possible at all?
(it seems like an endless loop..)

Comment: where do you want it to be routed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, you have to do a check before and redirect to Controller:: setAction

Checkout:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction